# Paris CDG Airport to Disneyland Paris when arriving late at night?

Tags: public-transport, paris, cdg, disney

This weekend I am flying into CDG airport arriving at 20:50. What is the best/cheapest/easiest way of getting to Disneyland?

I've looked at trains, easy, fast, relatively cheap but the last one is at 21:55, not sure if that's makable. The Disney shuttle doesn't seem to run that late. I can hire a car for £40 for the whole weekend, but I've never driven on the right side of the road before (I'm British) and would be a smidge apprehensive.

I'm guessing taxi is crazy expensive. And walking definitely out of the picture. Am I missing something? Is an hour at most time enough to get through airport security and find the train? I fly into the terminal of the train station so wouldn't need any internal shuttle, so that saves time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to my own experience, you should be able to make it from the plane to the train in less than one hour. But if you have checked-in luggage, the delay might not help...

It will be too late to take the Magic Shuttle as the last one is before 8 PM.

The 2 other options I am thinking about :

- take a Uber (46-62€ with Uber X)
- go with the RER via Paris (this will take a lot of time and won't necessary be really cheaper than Uber)

Comment: We only have carry on, so that saves the wait at baggage. Could you estimate the uber cost? The convenience of it seems definitely preferable to going into Paris.

Comment: I added the price estimation for Uber X after a quick calculation on their website : 46 to 62 €.

Comment: We found in the end a shuttle service that will do to and from for €75 ,so went for that option. It comes with a man with a sign with my name on at the airport, which was the clincher.

Comment: While potentially not valid at this time, we simply used a TGV which got us to the gates of Disneyland Paris in about 15 minutes. We also had nothing but hand luggage, and were coming from the UK pre-Brexit which meant we could essentially just stroll right through.

Answer (score 3):

The “normal” option is to take a train via Paris. Take RER B (any train from the airport) to Châtelet-Les-Halles then RER A to Marne-la-Vallée (the line has several branches, make sure your train goes to Marne-la-Vallée which is the last stop). You can look up schedules on the [RATP transport authority website](http://www.ratp.fr/itineraires/en/ratp/recherche-avancee) (you need to enter “Marne-la-Vallée-Chessy” for Disneyland). The [fare](http://www.ratp.fr/tarifs/en/ratp/resultat?depart=A%C3%A9roports+CDG+par+RER+B&arrivee=Marne-la-Vall%C3%A9e-Chessy-Parc+Disney&depart_id=358&arrivee_id=777) is €17.05 (€10.50 for children aged 4–10). It is a long trip (about 1½ hour total) but you'll get there.

Due to engineering works, if your plane is delayed, you might need to take a bus instead. There's free wifi in Roissy to check schedules (the RATP app is more convenient than the website if you don't know the local geography), accessible in the luggage delivery area but often not in the immigration queues.

There's also a slightly more expensive but a lot more convenient [direct bus](https://magicalshuttle.co.uk/shuttle/charles-de-gaulle-shuttle/) but it doesn't run in the evening.

Alternatively, a taxi will set you back ~70€ (night rate, not including supplements for 4+ passengers or luggage handling). Uber is typically around the same price (can be more or less depending on the trip and time).